# Looking for a simple javascript standard calculator

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm looking for an existing fully-working, simple standard calculator. I've seen several online ones, but nothing really fits my needs.

I need it to be javascript only (no Flash, but I don't care what javascript libraries it uses like jQuery, prototype, etc.), halfway-decent looking, with the functionality you'd get from a normal hand-held calculator (like the one found [here](http://delimiter.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/calculator.jpg)).

Basically, it just needs the 0-9 digits, decimal point, +-*/=, Clear, and a (+/-) key. Square root and (M)emory are not necessary, but are ok.

The closest I've been able to find was the [jQuery calculator](http://keith-wood.name/calculator.html) from Keith Wood, but that one is kind of a pain, and it's more for pop-up calculations on the fly. I'm looking for something that stands alone, no funky behavior, no relationship to a page, just something that looks and acts like a calculator.

I could build one myself in a day or two, but I don't really have the time.

It doesn't have to be free - we're willing to pay for a decent tool.

With all that in mind, does anyone have any ideas? Google has not been helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I would go with jQuery calculator. Hide the input, and show it automatically.

Comment: I may end up doing that - I tried it quickly awhile ago and it didn't quite work smoothly, but I may be able to work those issues out if I can't find anything better suited.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/trjsJ/ this is a very simple calc... you can add the (+/-) key...

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this : https://github.com/rcoelros/jquery-blackCalculator

Here is a [demo](http://blackhauz.com.br/blog/wp-content/examples/black_calculator/)

Comment: This doesn't have square-root.

Comment: @Shmiddty OP specifically said : `Square root and (M)emory are not necessary, but are ok.`

Comment: This one may work - looks like it's not quite finished, since it doesn't handle mistakes very well (clicking multiple operators in a row for example), but it may be a good starting point. Thanks

Comment: @PranavKapoor Ah, I looked at the image, and skipped that part.